# Use the same realm from UI and background service

Tags: xamarin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

If I try to use the same realm from UI and background service I got this error:

```
05-20 14:39:35.016 11464 11464 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:7.1.1/NYC/4729347:userdebug/test-keys'
05-20 14:39:35.017 11464 11464 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
05-20 14:39:35.017 11464 11464 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86'
05-20 14:39:35.017 11464 11464 F DEBUG   : pid: 11427, tid: 11452, name: est.aps.tracker  >>> fr.test.aps.tracker <<<
05-20 14:39:35.019 11464 11464 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
05-20 14:39:35.019 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     eax 00000000  ebx 00002ca3  ecx 00002cbc  edx 00000006
05-20 14:39:35.019 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     esi 8977f978  edi 8977f920
05-20 14:39:35.019 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
05-20 14:39:35.019 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     eip ae2f1424  ebp 8977f778  esp 8977f71c  flags 00200296
05-20 14:39:35.028 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :
05-20 14:39:35.028 11464 11464 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-20 14:39:35.028 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc ffffe424  [vdso:ae2f1000] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
05-20 14:39:35.028 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0007a03c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+28)
05-20 14:39:35.028 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00075885  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+85)
05-20 14:39:35.028 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0002785a  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+42)
05-20 14:39:35.028 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0001ee36  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+86)
05-20 14:39:35.030 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 0046bab4  /data/app/fr.test.aps-1/lib/x86/librealm-wrappers.so (_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+452)
05-20 14:39:35.034 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00433b17  /data/app/fr.test.aps-1/lib/x86/librealm-wrappers.so (_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+23)
05-20 14:39:35.034 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00433baf  /data/app/fr.test.aps-1/lib/x86/librealm-wrappers.so (_ZSt9terminatev+31)
05-20 14:39:35.034 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0046a73d  /data/app/fr.test.aps-1/lib/x86/librealm-wrappers.so (execute_native_thread_routine+141)
05-20 14:39:35.034 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
05-20 14:39:35.034 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
05-20 14:39:35.034 11464 11464 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
```

To isolate the problem I created a small [app](https://github.com/ElMoribond/TestRealm) consisting of a single page and a hybrid service.
This page has two buttons to stop/start a counter. She also displays a list of user objects (in ListView).

The service only displays a counter every 5 seconds in logcat window.
(it takes a few seconds for it to start)

I would like the service to modify the listview with the counter value in real time.
But I can not use a same realm at the same time from my UI and service.

In other words, I can not uncomment **at the same time** the two lines mentioned below:

```
Enable/disable usage of realm by background service:  
Uncomment/comment await in StartTrack method of Tracker.cs file.

Enable/disable usage of realm by UI:  
Uncomment/comment await in OnAppearing method of ServicePage.cs file.
```

PS:
Adapt Constants.cs with your valid ROS address, username and password.

EDIT: I simplified the code

Comment: Well, for one thing, you can not `Forms.Init` twice. I got lost after that on why you are using multiple realm contexts, from DBase and else where.....

Comment: I admit that it can be confusing. In fact it is by that that I made several tests. With or without DependencyService.

Comment: Keep it **simple to start**, create one Class that holds a static reference to your Realm instance and serve it up via a read-only property (I tend to init it in a Android Application subclass, but it does not really matter since it is static), now you can access it via your Android Service or your Forms' pages, etc... and remove that Forms.Init in your Service.

Comment: @sushihangover Thanks for your interest :) If I understand you correctly the two threads (UI and service) must access the static realm via DependencyService (Android)? that's right?

Comment: You can do it that way, or place that class in your Forms project (PCL/NetStd) and your Android Service can create an instance of that Class (that holds the static Realm reference, which you can create in its `.ctor`) and your Forms code can do the same thing. Just do not reference any Forms code within that Class (i.e. the Service should be able to run without any references to an initiated Forms app.)

Comment: @SushiHangover As you advise me I simplified and create a static class but I have exactly the same problem. Would I have misunderstood your idea?